# terminate all processes in a Pool

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a python script that looks like follows:

```
import os
import tempfile
from multiprocessing import Pool

def runReport(a, b, c):
    # do task.
    temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    if (os.path.isfile(temp_dir + "/stop_check")):
        # How to terminate all processes in the pool here?

def runReports(args):
    return runReport(*args)

def main(argv):
    pool = Pool(4)
    args = []
    # Code to generate args. args is an array of tuples of form (a, b, c)
    pool.map(runReports, args)

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
main(sys.argv[1:])
```

There is another python script that creates this file /tmp/stop_check.
When this file gets created, I need to terminate the Pool. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking "How to terminate a multiprocessing.Pool?" or "How to listen for a file creation event?"

Comment: `pool.terminate()` will terminate the processes in the pool.

Comment: @plg I am very new to python, I tried passing the pool to runReport function so that I can call `pool.terminate()` there. But I was not able to do so as pool is not pickle-able. I need to find a way to call `pool.terminate()` when the file /tmp/stop_check is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the parent process can terminate the pool. You're better off having the parent run a loop that checks for the existence of that file, rather than trying to have each child do it and then signal the parent somehow:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import tempfile
from multiprocessing import Pool

def runReport(*args):
    # do task

def runReports(args):
    return runReport(*args)

def main(argv):
    pool = Pool(4)
    args = []
    # Code to generate args. args is an array of tuples of form (a, b, c)
    result = pool.map_async(runReports, args)
    temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    while not result.ready():
        if os.path.isfile(temp_dir + "/stop_check"):
            pool.terminate()
            break
        result.wait(.5) # Wait a bit to avoid pegging the CPU. You can tune this value as you see fit.

if (__name__ == '__main__'):
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

By using `map_async` instead of `map`, you're free to have the parent use a loop to check for the existence of the file, and then terminate the pool when necessary. Do not that using `terminate` to kill the children means that they won't get to do any clean up at all, so you need to make sure none of them access resources that could get left in an inconsistent state if the process dies while using them.